# spring - hibernate 5 naming strategy configuration

Tags: spring, configuration, hibernate-5.x

I am writing application using postgresql database and spring + hibernate frameworks.

I upgraded spring framework from 4.1.5.RELEASE to 4.2.0.RELEASE version and upgraded hibernate framework from 4.3.7.Final to 5.0.0.Final version.

After upgrade I have problems with NamingStrategy. In postgresql database, table column names are in lowercase separated by underscore, in application layer, bean properties are in camelcase.

This is working spring configuration file for older version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="fms" />

    <bean id="microFmsDataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="***" />
        <property name="username" value="***" />
        <property name="password" value="***" />

        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="100" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="microFmsDataSource"/>

        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>fms</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

After upgrade I changed NamingStrategy configuration:

```
<entry key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
```

like this:

```
<entry key="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy" value="***" />
```

and tried all variants of options listed in hibernate javadoc: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html#IMPLICIT_NAMING_STRATEGY

but with no success.

Can you tell me what is alternative of ImprovedNamingStrategy in Hibernate 5 and provide a working configuration example ?

Comment: I used     <prop key="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">legacy-jpa</prop> and it worked for me. Can you try ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImprovedNamingStrategy no longer working in Hibernate 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437202/improvednamingstrategy-no-longer-working-in-hibernate-5)

Answer (score 32):

I think I found the solution.

To achieve my goal, I used `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy` configuration, instead of `hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy`.

I created an implementation of the `PhysicalNamingStrategy` interface which simulates part of the functionality of the original `ImprovedNamingStrategy` class:

```
package fms.util.hibernate;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;

public class ImprovedNamingStrategy implements PhysicalNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalCatalogName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
        return convert(identifier);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
        return convert(identifier);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalSchemaName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
        return convert(identifier);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalSequenceName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
        return convert(identifier);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
        return convert(identifier);
    }

    private Identifier convert(Identifier identifier) {
        if (identifier == null || StringUtils.isBlank(identifier.getText())) {
            return identifier;
        }

        String regex = "([a-z])([A-Z])";
        String replacement = "$1_$2";
        String newName = identifier.getText().replaceAll(regex, replacement).toLowerCase();
        return Identifier.toIdentifier(newName);
    }
}
```

After I created this class, I changed my configuration from:

```
<entry key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
```

to this:

```
<entry key="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" value="fms.util.hibernate.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
```

and now everything works correctly.

This solution covers only small part of `ImprovedNamingStrategy`. In my project, for table mapping and join mapping, I always specify the name of table or join column explicitly. I rely on implicit name conversion only for column names. So this simple solution was acceptable for me.

This is a full example of my Spring configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="fms" />

    <bean id="microFmsDataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="***" />
        <property name="username" value="***" />
        <property name="password" value="***" />

        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="100" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="microFmsDataSource"/>

        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>fms</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" value="fms.util.hibernate.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

I hope this solution will be helpful for somebody. :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I just ran into this problem. Your solution didn't work for me. It only fixes the camelcase=>underscore. It doesn't fix the other difference between the ImprovedNamingStrategy and the JPA standard, namely the _id-suffix. The standard creates an _id-suffix on foreign key columns, which the ImporvedNamingStrategy doesn't. Do you have a fix for that as well?

Comment: @AleksanderBlomskøld You are right, this solution covers only small part of ImprovedNamingStrategy. In my project, for table mapping and join mapping, I always specify name of table or join column explicitly. I rely on implicit name conversion only for column names. So this simple solution was acceptable for me.

Comment: It is incorrect to say 'For the task I want to accomplish, must be used "hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" configuration'. The same effect can be achieved by using implementation of `ImplicitNamingStrategy`. 'there is no implementation of PhysicalNamingStrategy interface' is incorrect too see  [PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.html) as an example.

Comment: @v.ladynev Thanks for correction, I corrected the answer.

Comment: See also @samuel-andrés solution for extending `PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437202/improvednamingstrategy-no-longer-working-in-hibernate-5)

Comment: Spring Boot 1.4 update: You can now use Spring's [SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/hibernate/SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.html) like this (yml):

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`

Answer (score 11):

For anyone looking for a Java Config Solution

The `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy` property seems split into two parts in hibernate 5.X:

`hibernate.physical_naming_strategy`

`hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy`

Spring provides `SpringImplicitNamingStrategy` and `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` for this purpose.

Here is my approach:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@DependsOn("myDataSource")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManagerFactory",
        basePackages={"com.myapp.repo"},
        transactionManagerRef="myTransactionManager"
        )
public class MyJpaConfig {

    private Map<String, Object> properties;

    public MyJpaConfig() {
        properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());

    }

    @Bean(name = "myEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("systemDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean build = builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.myapp.entity")
                .properties(properties)
                .build();
        return build;

    }

    @Bean(name = "myTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager myTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("myEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory myEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(myEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the exactly same problem. I fixed it with default implementation from spring boot:

```
<property name="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy" value="org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy" />
<property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" value="org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy" />
```

Answer (score 5):

This work for me, from http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <!-- convert aaBb to aa_bb -->
    <property name="PhysicalNamingStrategy">
        <bean class="fms.util.hibernate.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
    </property>

    <!-- convert aa_bb to aaBb -->
    <property name="ImplicitNamingStrategy">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl" />
    </property>
...
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.xxx.pojo"});
    // -----important-----
    localSessionFactoryBean.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new CustomNamingStrategy());
    return localSessionFactoryBean;
}

public class CustomNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {***
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find below 3 points that I discovered while working on Naming Strategy:

1. If you are providing `@Table` and `@Column` annotation in your entity classes with names provided with an underscore i.e. **user_id** i.e. `@Column(name="user_id")`, it will take the column name as **user_id**; if you give it as **userid** then it will change to **user_id** if you use no strategy or implicit strategy (specifically `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl`). So, if you want a strategy where the entity attribute name changes to one with underscore and lowercase letters i.e. something from **userId** to **user_id**, you should use implicit or no strategy (which actually uses implicit strategy).
2. If you don't want your naming strategy to add an underscore to the column name or class name, then the strategy that you need to use would look like:
   `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`. The things that you provide in annotations `@Table` and `@Column’s` name attribute would remain as it is.
3. If you don't want to provide annotations and want to manually handle the table name and column names, you should extend the class `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` and override the required methods. If you still use annotations for some of the cases here, remember the overridden methods will apply on the names written in those annotations.

Comment: @MohamadShahrestani can you please suggest some edits?

Comment: Done, but for better answer read this link for being better in Stackoverflow : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question