# Implementing a NamingStrategy in Hibernate 5 (make autogenerated column names UPPERCASE)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to let Hibernate auto generate the database starting from the entities, however I want them all UPPERCASE.

This used to work in the past now I have messed up column names with Upper and Lower case letters.

I enabled the

```
.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create")
```

to let Hibernate auto generate the database, and I created an UppercaseNamingStrategy.java extending **org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy**.

According to https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-namingstrategy

Now I should

> You can specify a different strategy by calling
>   Configuration.setNamingStrategy() before adding mappings:
>
> ```
> SessionFactory sf = new Configuration()
> .setNamingStrategy(ImprovedNamingStrategy.INSTANCE)
> .addFile("Item.hbm.xml")
> .addFile("Bid.hbm.xml")
> .buildSessionFactory();
> ```
>
> org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy is a built-in strategy that
>   might be a useful starting point for some applications.

Configuration.setNamingStrategy() however seems to be no more in Hibernate 5.0.6.

I would of course like to do it programatically (I don't have .xml configuration files and don't want them).

**NOTE:**

Using

.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "my.project.hibernate.UppercaseNamingStrategy")

doesn't work as well, seems to be ignored altogether...

Comment: Try to override this https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl.html.

Comment: This is another solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165694/spring-hibernate-5-naming-strategy-configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate 5 uses two new interfaces for name strategies `PhysicalNamingStrategy` and `ImplicitNamingStrategy`. You need just implement `PhysicalNamingStrategy`. It is called by Hibernate after all column names are created for model. So you can just make it uppercase. Hibernate uses by default [`PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.0.CR3/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.java), that do nothing. You can just extend it

```
public class UpperCaseNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return context.getIdentifierHelper().toIdentifier(
            StringUtils.upperCase(name.getText(), Locale.ENGLISH));
    }

}
```

You can build session factory with `UpperCaseNamingStrategy` by this way

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new UpperCaseNamingStrategy());
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

I am working on a more complex name strategy now. You can refer [Hibernate5NamingStrategy](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/cfg/strategy/hibernate5/Hibernate5NamingStrategy.java) if you are interested.

Comment: Thankyou, upgrading to Hibernate 5 and extending PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl fixed it.Just a quick rant: why do they have to change the name of methods and classes and leave the documentation unchanged?? Please, keep updating code and leave naming as is.

Comment: @sarah.ferguson You are welcome. Looks like, Hibernate always had a poor documentation. It is interesting that there is the `ImprovedNamingStrategy` class in Hibernate 5, but you can't use it anymore.

Comment: Hey @v.ladynev thanks for this information. Just a quick question, what if I wanted to configure my app via persistence.xml?

Comment: @Kikin-Sama Sorry, I don't still investigate using the naming strategies with JPA.