# How define naming strategy for Hibernate bean using Spring?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, orm

I overrided all ImprovedNamingStrategy methods and placed for them breakpoints, but methods were not called in debug mode.

I have only one hibernate factory, so mistake because of other instance is impossible.

I think, the problem is in the key "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" or no?

```
    <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">{hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">
                com.stub.utilities.dao.sql.hibernate.LowerCaseNamingStrategy
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Pom

```
<spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
<hibernate.core.version>5.0.7.Final</hibernate.core.version>
```

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate 5 doesn't have any `ImprovedNamingStrategy`. It uses `ImplicitNamingStrategy` and `PhysicalNamingStrategy` interfaces. Strictly speaking, there is the class `ImprovedNamingStrategy`, for an example, in the Hibernate 5.1. But you can't use it to configure the `SessionFactory`.

An example to set `ImplicitNamingStrategy`

```
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="implicitNamingStrategy">
      <bean class="com.github.fluent.hibernate.cfg.strategy.hibernate5.Hibernate5NamingStrategy">
        <property name="tablePrefix" value="spring_" />
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

You can use `hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy` and `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy` properties as well

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">
                  com.stub.utilities.dao.sql.hibernate.ImplicitNamingStrategy
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy">
                  com.stub.utilities.dao.sql.hibernate.PhysicalNamingStrategy
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

You can refer my other answer about how to implement `LowerCaseNamingStrategy`

[Implementing a NamingStrategy in Hibernate 5 (make autogenerated column names UPPERCASE)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34956988/3405171)