# JPA Uppercase table names

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

I have a table in Postgresql:

```
CREATE TABLE "UTILISATEUR"(
 
 "IdUtilisateur" serial NOT NULL,
 "Nom" character varying(50),
 "Prenom" character varying(50),
 "Profil" character varying(50),
 "Pseudo" character varying(20),
 "IdSite" integer DEFAULT 0,
 "Password" character varying(1024),
  id_role integer,
  )
```

and I am trying Map on this Table So I used `@Table` JPA annotation (see below). This is my `application.propreties`:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/baseecu
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password =root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL 
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update 
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

and finaly this is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UTILISATEUR")
public class Utilisateur   {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
@Column(name="IdUtilisateur")
public Long id ;
public String Nom ; 
public String Prenom ; 
public String Profil ; 
public String Pseudo ; 


public String Password ;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_role")
public Role role ;
public Long getId() {
    return id;
```

If I have it like this `@Table(name="UTILISATEUR")` I get msg from PostgreSQL

```
ERREUR: la relation « utilisateur » n'existe pas
```

When I try to escape quote `@Table(name="\"UTILISATEUR\"")`

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"
```

I tried the responses from this question but it doesn't work

[Spring boot JPA insert in TABLE with uppercase name with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571848/spring-boot-jpa-insert-in-table-with-uppercase-name)

## update

I've been searching about ImprovedNamingstrategy it's seems like an issue in spring boot instead I've used EJB3NamingStrategy and also DefaultNamingStrategy it's not working what funny it's when Hibernate execute the SQL the result is pretty confusing :

```
Hibernate: select utilisateu0_.IdUtilisateur as IdUtilis1_2_, utilisateu0_.Nom as Nom2_2_, utilisateu0_.Password as Password3_2_, utilisateu0_.Prenom as Prenom4_2_, utilisateu0_.Profil as Profil5_2_, utilisateu0_.Pseudo as Pseudo6_2_, utilisateu0_.id_role as id_role7_2_ from UTILISATEUR utilisateu0_
```

It's like it knows the table name is in UPPERCASE but does not want to map or I don't know what wrong with it this is the result of using

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
or 
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
```

and also the EJB3NamingStrategy

This is also the result when I use the annotation like that

```
@Table(name="UTILISATEUR")
```

and I also tried like that

```
@Table(name="\"UTILISATEUR\"")
```

and I get the issue

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"

Hibernate: select utilisateu0_.IdUtilisateur as IdUtilis1_2_, utilisateu0_.Nom as Nom2_2_, utilisateu0_.Password as Password3_2_, utilisateu0_.Prenom as Prenom4_2_, utilisateu0_.Profil as Profil5_2_, utilisateu0_.Pseudo as Pseudo6_2_, utilisateu0_.id_role as id_role7_2_ from `UTILISATEUR` utilisateu0_
```

finally this is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.xx.MDValidation</groupId>
<artifactId>xx.MDValidation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>xx.MDValidation</name>
<description>Projet Validation xx</description>

<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
<hibernate.version>4.2.21.Final</hibernate.version>
<commons-dbcp.version>1.2.2</commons-dbcp.version>
</properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        
    </dependency>

    
        <dependency>
<groupId>postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bsf</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsf</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The best approach is to never use quoted identifiers - they are much more trouble then they are worth it.

Comment: I know that But I can't touch database structure :/  it's those project where they have the database and you are going to use it

Comment: In the JPA implementation I use (DataNucleus) I can simply set a persistence property to "lowercase" or "UPPERCASE" and it does the necessary changes to what is specified, and all works. Maybe your chosen implementation has something like that?

Comment: could you explain please what you just said !

Comment: In my opinion what you can do is implement a [custom naming strategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html) to convert entity names to their corresponding table names.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate you use?

Comment: @v.ladynev hibernate-core-4.3.11

Comment: @Bunti Am already using it in the application propreties

Comment: I have just checked the usage of quoted table identifier with JPA (hibernate 5.0.3) and Derby, and with these it's OK. I can use @Entity(name="\"FFiirrmm\"") and everything is as expected. Can you show us the whole "syntax error" message?

Comment: `unexpected char: '"' [select generatedAlias0 from "UTILISATEUR" as generatedAlias0]` i got this error when i use it like you did

Comment: @riskop I think it is a Hibernate 4 problem.

Comment: @KamelMili Can you try Hibernate 5 just for a test.

Comment: okey so am using JPA 2.1 and they said hibernate 5 is supported so am going to add hibernate 5 in the maven dependencies

Comment: @KamelMili You will not be able to use `org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy`

Comment: then i will not be able to name my table in uppercase or lower case so :/

Comment: @KamelMili You can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949839/implementing-a-namingstrategy-in-hibernate-5-make-autogenerated-column-names-up/34956988#34956988

Comment: i'll tried out :D Thank you for everything

Comment: If you are using postgres, then why are you working with a Mysql Dialect?!

Comment: do you have an idea of should i use instead

Comment: According to the documentation All identifiers (including column names) that are not double-quoted are folded to lower case in PostgreSQL. Column names that were created with double-quotes and thereby retained upper-case letters (and/or other syntax violations) have to be double-quoted for the rest of their life. Did you try to lower case the table name?

Comment: I did escape it was a dialect problem i could not change table name because my client is using the database in another app

Comment: I tried to simulate your problem, but I can't found any problem with your case:
https://github.com/xsalefter/stackoverflowmvn

Could you try this and see what happened on your machine? FYI: I'm using ubuntu 15.10 and PostgreSQL 9.4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

maybe because you are using MYSQL5DIALECT there's a Postgres Dialect just used post it like this and for the improved naming strategy use EJB3 like 
[Spring boot JPA insert in TABLE with uppercase name with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571848/spring-boot-jpa-insert-in-table-with-uppercase-name)

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

hope it works for you

Comment: for people use newer version: `PostgreSQLDialect` is Deprecated: use `PostgreSQL82Dialect` instead doc: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQLDialect.html

Answer (score 9):

I reproduced your UTILISATEUR table (role removed) in postgres 8.4 and hibernate 5.0.3.

It works as expected with explicit table and column names annotation:

```
@Entity(name="\"UTILISATEUR\"")
public class Utilisateur {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    @Column(name="\"IdUtilisateur\"")
    private Long id ;

    @Column(name="\"Nom\"")
    private String Nom ; 
    @Column(name="\"Prenom\"")
    private String Prenom ; 
    @Column(name="\"Profil\"")
    private String Profil ; 
    @Column(name="\"Pseudo\"")
    private String Pseudo ; 

    @Column(name="\"Password\"")
    private String Password ;

    ... getter / setters

}
```

Comment: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '"' [select generatedAlias0 from "UTILISATEUR" as generatedAlias0]

Comment: Can you try running this against your db? http://peter.risko.hu/java_incubator/JPA_Postgres_quoted_identifiers_test.zip

Comment: this is another structure i can't use this

Comment: Well, if I were you, I'd try to narrow down the problem. I would create a simplified Utilisateur table and concentrate on the case sensitive table name / column names. My first step would be to assure, that it's possible to handle the simplified case without error. If that is working, then I would start modifying the working -- albeit simplified -- solution to make it more similar to the actual system (more columns, table connections, queries etc.). The code I attached can be your first step in this direction.

Comment: Thank you for everything riskop you've done a lot so long

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your application with the next line depend the database:

MySql

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
```

Postgres

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Oracle

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```