# The column name X was not found in this ResultSet - JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, wildfly

So I have this Company entity, I'm having an error every time I add a company.
I'm using PostgreSQL for my database and I use double quote literals to map the columns of the table in pascalcase.

Company entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="\"Id\"")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="\"Name\"")
    private String name;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Company Endpoint:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/companies")
public class CompanyEndpoint {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
    private EntityManager em;

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response create(Company entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return Response.created(
                UriBuilder.fromResource(CompanyEndpoint.class)
                        .path(String.valueOf(entity.getId())).build()).build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id:[0-9][0-9]*}")
    public Response deleteById(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        Company entity = em.find(Company.class, id);
        if (entity == null) {
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
        em.remove(entity);
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id:[0-9][0-9]*}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response findById(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        TypedQuery<Company> findByIdQuery = em
                .createQuery(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Company c WHERE c.id = :entityId ORDER BY c.id",
                        Company.class);
        findByIdQuery.setParameter("entityId", id);
        Company entity;
        try {
            entity = findByIdQuery.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            entity = null;
        }
        if (entity == null) {
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(entity).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Company> listAll(@QueryParam("start") Integer startPosition,
            @QueryParam("max") Integer maxResult) {
        TypedQuery<Company> findAllQuery = em
                .createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Company c ORDER BY c.id",
                        Company.class);
        if (startPosition != null) {
            findAllQuery.setFirstResult(startPosition);
        }
        if (maxResult != null) {
            findAllQuery.setMaxResults(maxResult);
        }
        final List<Company> results = findAllQuery.getResultList();
        return results;
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{id:[0-9][0-9]*}")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response update(@PathParam("id") Long id, Company entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
        if (id == null) {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
        if (!id.equals(entity.getId())) {
            return Response.status(Status.CONFLICT).entity(entity).build();
        }
        if (em.find(Company.class, id) == null) {
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
        try {
            entity = em.merge(entity);
        } catch (OptimisticLockException e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT)
                    .entity(e.getEntity()).build();
        }

        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

The last I'm seeing is `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name "Id" was not found in this ResultSet.`

Can someone explain what is wrong in my code. Thank you in advance.

Full sever log:

```
2017-02-09 13:37:40,650 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-15) UT005023: Exception handling request to /test/rest/companies: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [test.model.Company]

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:77)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:220)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:175)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:418)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)

    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)

    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)

    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)

    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [test.model.Company]

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)

    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)

    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)

    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)

    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)

    at org.jboss.tools.examples.rest.CompanyEndpoint$$$view398.create(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)

    ... 43 more

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [test.model.Company]

    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)

    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)

    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)

    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1152)

    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:580)

    at org.jboss.tools.examples.rest.CompanyEndpoint.create(CompanyEndpoint.java:37)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)

    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)

    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)

    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)

    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)

    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)

    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)

    ... 87 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [test.model.Company]

    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)

    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)

    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)

    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:49)

    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2803)

    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3374)

    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)

    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:619)

    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:273)

    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254)

    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299)

    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317)

    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)

    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)

    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)

    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)

    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)

    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)

    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)

    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775)

    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748)

    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753)

    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)

    ... 118 more

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name "Id" was not found in this ResultSet.

    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2591)

    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2489)

    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getLong(WrappedResultSet.java:1583)

    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.get(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:138)

    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.getGeneratedIdentity(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:73)

    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:61)

    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)

    ... 137 more
```

Comment: You can conclude that PostgreSQL DEFAULTS to "lowercase" column namings UNLESS YOU QUOTE THEM. Some JPA providers provide a nice easy setting to auto-quote them for you.

Comment: Just don't put quotes around your column names.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your program looks for a column named '"Id"', instead of 'Id'. You should change your annotation this way.

```
@Column(name="Id")
private Long id;
```

Comment: Thanks but this your answer is not what I'm looking for, it generates columns in lowercase not in pascalcase
CREATE TABLE test.company
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT company_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Comment: I've never used postgres nor ran into problems with uppercase or lowercase sql statements. Maybe this link help can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165694/spring-hibernate-5-naming-strategy-configuration

Comment: jaysee - thanks I've implemented a naming strategy in pascalcase but still I having an error "The column name "Id" was not found in this ResultSet" during insertion in db.

Comment: @netto did you find a solution I've got the same error

Comment: @el_pup_le Yes I have found a trick to avoid these error but I don't use anymore entity manager's insert(forgot what is called) method... I just execute a normal sql by using .executeUpdate() method...

Answer (score 0):

I speak Spanish and for this answer I use google translator: it marked me the same error but with java and the reason was to send through the rs a value that is not in your select query, for example (`"SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Company c ORDER BY c.id ", Company.class);` Maybe the id is misspelled in the column and because it is not found when wanting to pass that data to another element, it marks the error.

this is my code:

```
String sql = "select p.nombre_paciente, p.apellido_paciente, p.nacimiento_paciente, p.edad_paciente, p.cedula_paciente, p.profesion_paciente,p.dlaboral_paciente,p.dparticular_paciente,p.tlaboral_paciente,p.tparticular_paciente,c.idcivil,c.tipo,**p.id_paciente** from paciente p inner join civil c on p.idcivil = c.idcivil where upper(nombre_paciente) like '%" + nombre.toUpperCase() + "%'"
                    + " order by id_paciente offset " + offset + " limit " + utiles.Utiles.REGISTROS_PAGINA;
    System.out.println("--->" + sql);
    try (PreparedStatement ps = Conexion.getConn().prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        String tabla = "";
        while (rs.next()) {
            tabla += "<tr>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getInt("id_paciente") + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getString("nombre_paciente") + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getString("apellido_paciente") + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getDate("nacimiento_paciente") + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getInt("edad_paciente") + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getString("cedula_paciente") + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getString("profesion_paciente") + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getString("dlaboral_paciente") + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getString("dparticular_paciente") + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getString("tlaboral_paciente") + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getString("tparticular_paciente") + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getInt("idcivil") + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + rs.getString("tipo") + "</td>"
            + "</tr>";
```

what was marked in bold was not there and when implementing it, the error disappeared.
Ps .: I know it's a lot of text

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions=true
```

When you create table, Did you use double quotes to column name? If not, they will be folded to lowercase in PostgreSQL