# JPA - Map Serial(Primary Key) Datatype for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I'm developing a simple app and I used `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` for primary key and it generates int datatype in database. Is there a way to tell JPA through mapping that I want to generate serial datatype in database not int datatype?

Company:

```
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name="Company_Id_seq",
            sequenceName="\"Company_Id_seq\"",
            schema="test",
            allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="Company_Id_seq")
    @Column(name = "\"Id\"", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
```

PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test."Company"
(
  "Id" integer NOT NULL,
```

What I want:

```
CREATE TABLE test."Company"
(
  "Id" serial NOT NULL,
```

Comment: and what happens when you use "IDENTITY" generation strategy? i.e the thing that equates to "SERIAL" database type

Comment: I have an issue using "IDENTITY" but yes, it generates serial datatype. Please refer to this link for my issue using "IDENTITY" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239134/the-column-name-x-was-not-found-in-this-resultset-jpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SEQUENCE` is not for use when you have an "auto-incrementing" column type in the datastore. For that situation you should use `IDENTITY` strategy